# Varnish and Apache Document Root

Tags: varnish, apache2, documentroot

I've inherited a system with a Debian 8 with an Apache installed and multiple VirtualHosts. In my 000-default.conf file I've got /var/www/ as document root, not /var/www/html and I can't found anywhere a DocumentRoot with /var/www/html.

Now I've installed varnish, and not to complicate it I'm running it in 6081 default port. So if I ask a http://mylanip:6081 I expect my varnish returns me the document root /var/www, but it's returning /var/www/html.

I have told varnish that he has the backend at port 80 so it's ok, but... why is showing my /var/www/html and not /var/www/??

Comment: I run "apache2ctl -S" and I see a line with: "Main DocumentRoot: /var/www/html" so that's the error, I don't know where to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an Apache problem. It was missing the next line in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

I guess Apache uses /var/www/html as default DocumentRoot if not specified